# Excel does strange things with my date data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, m, excel-dates

I want to convert my cells with a date from general to date. However, when I do this, some errors occur. Both just in my workbook as in my query editor.

Example, these cells have date in them but are marked as general:

[image: Before cell to date change]

And when I change it to date, it will change in this

[image: After cell to date change]

And this is the exact content of the cells:

| Date 1 | Date 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 3/2/2022 | 12/20/2023 |
| 7/15/2022 | 12/18/2023 |
| 12/21/2021 | 12/15/2023 |
| 2/2/2022 | 12/15/2023 |
| 3/23/2022 | 12/14/2023 |
| 1/17/2022 | 12/14/2023 |
| 2/1/2022 | 12/13/2023 |
| 6/14/2021 | 12/12/2023 |
| 1/16/2022 | 12/11/2023 |
| 2/9/2022 | 12/8/2023 |

I tried forcing "/" into "-" with replace all, but this doesn't make a difference so far

**EDIT:**
I changed format cells into this but that doesn't solve the problem: (if this is the correct way to do so)

[image: Format Cells]

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable. There are no dates with the month greater than 12.

Comment: To put it another way, your input dates are strings that would represent valid dates if you parsed then as `m/d/yyyy`, but you're parsing them as `d/m/yyyy`.

Comment: How can I change this? It is US data I received, so I would think it will have the correct date data-format. I cannot change how I will receive this date data, can I change something in my workbook? It is a large data set, so manually changing it won't work.

Comment: It's not the source that is the problem. It's how they're being parsed. Nothing is inherently in the correct format until you actually parse it. You haven't received US data, you've just received strings that look like US dates. How you parse them makes the difference.

Comment: I changed the format to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9plS.png (also see picture after edit at the bottom of my question) This doesn't solve the problem. This is not the correct way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried using the `Text To Columns` and then selecting the date parameter in the third step as `MDY` or `DMY` as per your regional settings date format, it usually resolves the problem or if in Power Query have you tried using the locale for dates?

Comment: It seems that your data is text, not dates. They'll only become dates when you parse them. You are parsing them incorrectly. No amount of formatting will change strings.

Comment: I second that what is commented by @Enigmativity Sir. Formatting is facade its the underlining cells which determines the calculations in excel not the displayed one. Also if you are using `MS365` with the updated version text looking dates gets converted to actual dates by adding `=--&datecellref ` or `=datecellref+0` if you are using US Date Settings.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya thank you!! Text to columns with MDY fixed the problem!
@ Enigmativity What is the proper way to parse the data outside of the query? Just inside a regular sheet.

Comment: @MMM - You can only do one notification per comment on this site.

Comment: @MMM - You can parse in the query or in the sheet. It's up to you. There's no proper place.

Answer (score 1):

In PQ, make sure you parse using locale and then you can specify the locale:

[image]

[image]